# Is Grand Canyon Rim Trail longer than 5.4 mi?

Tags: usa, hiking, national-parks, grand-canyon, arizona

Different sources give different length of the Grand Canyon Rim Trail.

- [This website](https://www.alltrails.com/trail/us/arizona/grand-canyon-rim-trail) states that the distance of the Grand Canyon Rim Trail is 5.4 miles.
- [This document](https://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/upload/RimTrail.pdf) says that the trail length is 12.6 miles (if you sum up all the distances in the table). If I construct a route on Google Maps using the destinations listed in [this document](https://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/upload/RimTrail.pdf), Google Maps kind of confirms the distance, [estimating it as 13.4 miles](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/South+Kaibab+Trailhead,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ/Pipe+Creek+Vista,+E+Rim+Dr,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ+86023/Yavapai+Point/Trail+View+Point/Maricopa+Point,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ/Powell+Point,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ/Hopi+Point,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ/The+Abyss,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ/Pima+Point,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ/Hermit's+Rest+Viewpoint,+Grand+Canyon+Village,+AZ/@36.0642415,-112.1905923,12.73z/data=!4m62!4m61!1m5!1m1!1s0x87331079f83ee3c7:0xb2d16755e4162e26!2m2!1d-112.0839461!2d36.0529569!1m5!1m1!1s0x8733107fb95b135b:0x36d3b1454174da4b!2m2!1d-112.0929211!2d36.0479523!1m5!1m1!1s0x873310ea49a13961:0xb4431b28280c019c!2m2!1d-112.1166801!2d36.0660209!1m5!1m1!1s0x873317327dbd4fbf:0x4e81f8d219c42870!2m2!1d-112.146986!2d36.0619162!1m5!1m1!1s0x8733172c571f885f:0x995a688a9492670b!2m2!1d-112.1462809!2d36.0699828!1m5!1m1!1s0x87331728e0b18db3:0x771a75c855a891ab!2m2!1d-112.1512208!2d36.0732299!1m5!1m1!1s0x87331727f0153709:0xee2d7e59eea3af89!2m2!1d-112.1549472!2d36.0744361!1m5!1m1!1s0x87331716703c44e7:0xf3842021e12caff7!2m2!1d-112.1691254!2d36.0581204!1m5!1m1!1s0x8733165229d01917:0x19487075f5a357c7!2m2!1d-112.2001712!2d36.0719269!1m5!1m1!1s0x873317b5b9a236bb:0x5c6ec84be4b778b8!2m2!1d-112.21248!2d36.06076!3e2).

So is there a mistake on the alltrails website? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The first link says "Grand Canyon Rim Trail is a 5.4 mile heavily trafficked ***out and back*** trail." The trail section marked in green on your second link, a PDF shows the trail as 1.1 + 1.7 = 2.8 miles, doubled is 5.6 out and back. There are numerous trails, many of which might be called "rim trail" anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hike described on alltrails is only one section of the Rim Trail described in the NPS document.  Inspecting the alltrails map, their hike starts at the point that NPS calls "Village Route Transfer", goes east to Mather Point, and then returns the same way.  The NPS guide shows the distance from Village Route Transfer to Mather Point as 1.2 + .7 + .7 = 2.6 miles, which when doubled is exactly the 5.4 listed on alltrails.